# Uncaught TypeError: Object x has no method 'css'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a little new to this so hopefully this question is acceptable, it may be a really simple fix but I can't seem to work out what is wrong.

I am having some trouble with defining a variable to use with jQuery, I have 12 div box's with 12 different IDs and I want to select them by number.

The code I am using is this:

```
//random number
$(document).ready(function(){
    r= Math.floor(Math.random()*13);
    console.log("The random number is: "+r);
});

//select random square
$(document).ready(function(){
    rs = "$("+"'"+"#circle"+r+"'"+")";
    var s = rs;
    console.log(s);
    s.css("background-color" , "green");
});
```

When I run this, the veriable RS returns the following error message in console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object $('#circlex') has no method 'css'

How do I correctly do this?

Comment: rs is just a string. string prototype doesn't have a css function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change this line, you are initializing the rs variable as a string instead of a Jquery object.

```
rs = $("#circle"+r);
var s = rs; //add inverted comma
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need one `$(document).ready(function(){` and also you can remove some redundant codes and mistake, just need:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    r= Math.floor(Math.random()*13);
    var rs = $("#circle"+r);
    rs.css("background-color" , "green");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

no need ""

```
var rs = $("#circle"+r);
rs.css("background-color" , "green");
```

you no need new var

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
rs = "$("+"'"+"#circle"+r+"'"+")";
```

with

```
rs = $('#circle' + r );
```